# What's the best strategy for complex sorting a list() as string

Tags: vb.net, sorting

I have a simple list of customers:

```
    Dim CustArr() As String = GetOriginalList() 
    'customer list looks like this
    'Customer number, first name, last name
    '1234 John Doe
    '1500 Jane Smith
    'etc.
```

I can easily split the customer number, first name and last name by the space (don't worry about complications like suffixes or titles):

```
    'loop through the list of names
    For Each CustName As String In CustArr

        'split out each word within the names
        Dim spl() As String = CustName.Split(" ")

        'add to table or 2-dimensional array

    Next

    'sort by lastname then by first name then by customer number
```

I know how to take the spl() and add to table or array. I would like to end up with a complex sort like Excel is capable of doing (but don't want to use Excel). I want to sort by last name then by first name then by customer number.

If it makes any difference, I want to output to a 2-dimensional array.

What is the best strategy to accomplish this? Use a dataTable? 2-dimensional array? Linq?

Comment: What are the two dimensions?

Comment: Three columns with first name, last name and customer number; has many customers

Comment: In that case, Tim Schmelter's answer using a List of a custom class is likely to be an excellent choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of an array i would use a custom class which is more readable and maintainable:

```
Class Customer
    Property Number As String
    Property LastName As String
    Property FirstName As String
End Class
```

Now you can use LINQ to select and order the customers from the lines:

```
Dim CustArr() As String = GetOriginalList() 
Dim customers As IEnumerable(Of Customer) =
    From line In CustArr.Skip(1) ' skip the header line '
    Let cols = line.Split({" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    Where cols.Length = 3
    Select c = New Customer With {
        .Number = cols(0).Trim(),
        .FirstName = cols(1).Trim(),
        .LastName = cols(2).Trim()
    }
    Order By c.LastName, c.FirstName, c.Number
Dim customerList As List(Of Customer) = customers.ToList()
```

Comment: This is beautiful code! So I can use Linq to query an array and split it simultaneously. I really need to upgrade my skills.

Comment: ach! so lange nicht zu Deutschland; Ich möchte wieder kommen

Comment: meine Vorfahren waren aus Deutschland, ich spreche ein wenig Deutsch, aber google translate hier geholfen

Comment: Can I use simple variables instead of properties for the class?

Comment: @D_Bester: Yes, you can. But properties are better since they ancapsulate the fields. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbteam/archive/2009/09/04/properties-vs-fields-why-does-it-matter-jonathan-aneja.aspx

Comment: Let and set no longer supported; so i removed the let

Comment: Line statements are no longer supported

Comment: @D_Bester: what means "no longer", [they are new](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531379.aspx). What framework version are you using?

Comment: Visual Studio 2008; .net 3.5

Comment: @D_Bester: as you can see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531379%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) it was introduced with 3.5 (VS 2008). But as far as i remember the implicit line continuation in LINQ queries was introduced with .NET 4 (VS 2010). I will edit my answer.

Comment: @D_Bester: [Here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Implicit-Line-Continuation-a044cbe0) is a link where you can see what implit line continuation means (the now redundant `_` at the end). But i have created a .NET 3.5 winforms project and my code above still works. So i don't know the problem.

Comment: I added Imports System.Linq at the top; do I need anything else?

Comment: @D_Bester: I don't know. You can use LINQ if this compiles `Dim one = {1, 2}.Take(1)`. Is your project an old project that you have upgraded to 3.5? Is it referencing the `System.Core` dll? Maybe you should ask nother question tagetting only this problem with reduced sample code and all necessary informations about the framework.

Comment: I have to use line continuation AND I had to remove the comment after Skip(1). Now I'm not getting errors. Thanks! I am testing it.

Comment: Huge thanks to you. I appreciate your help a lot. Best wishes!

Comment: @D_Bester: I'm glad I could help. But strange that my code works without line continuation even in .NET 3.5. But you're right, the comments were't allowed and after i removed the comments VS removed the `Let` and inserts parenthesis around the `Where` which caused compiler errors. So maybe it works if you remove the comments only.

Comment: For me, I had do both. Not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to use LINQ, and maybe restructuring your string arrays check this out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb688088.aspx